# What is the purpose of the ContainsPrefix method of the Web API IValueProvider interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've created some implementations of `IValueProvider` for my Web API project and I'm confused about the purpose of the `ContainsPrefix` method on the interface.

The `ContainsPrefix` method has this summary comment:

> Determines whether the collection contains the specified prefix.

However the summary of the method is abstract and doesn't explain what `prefix` will be provided to the method or what function the method serves. Is `prefix` going to be the action parameter name? The action name? The controller name? The first three letters of either of these? Does this method exist to automatically figure out which action parameter the `IValueProvider` should provide a value for?

I never see the `ContainsPrefix` method get called by the Web API framework in my `IValueProvider` implementations although I do see references in Web API's `CollectionModelBinder`, `MutableObjectModelBinder`, `SimpleModelBinderProvider`, and `CompositeValueProvider`. For instance, the following implementation has caused me no issues in my testing:

**MyValueProvider:**

```cs
public class MyValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        throw new NotYetImplementedException();
    }

    public ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        return new ValueProviderResult("hello", "hello", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

**TestController:**

```cs
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public string Get([ModelBinder]string input)
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

`GET` requests to my `TestController` will return *hello*, so I know `GetValue` is being called from `MyValueProvider`, but no exception is thrown so I know that `ContainsPrefix` isn't called.

1. When can I expect `ContainsPrefix` to be called by the Web API framework?
2. What `prefix` will be provided to this method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's strange that you were able to create value provider without knowing what this (quite important) method does.
First what value providers do? In short they provide values for parameters you specify in your actions. For example:

```
public ActionResult Index(string test) {

}
```

Here we have action with parameter named "test". Where to get value for it? From value providers. There are several built-in providers, like query string or form data providers. Those providers are invoked one by one, until some of the providers will be able to provide a value. For example, if there is query string parameter "test" - query string value provider will notice that and return a value, so other providers will not be invoked. Next, if post data contains parameter "test" - it will be used, and so on.

So this parameter name ("test" in this case), is what `ContainsPrefix` is called with. Take for example query string value provider. If query string contains no "test" - ContainsPrefix for this provider will return "false" and next value provider will be invoked. If it returns true - `GetValue` should return value and no other providers will be invoked.

If you want to provide a value for parameter from say cookie, in your `ContainsPrefix` method you will check if there is a cookie with given name. Note that it will be called only if all default value providers will fail to provide a value.

So, TLDR: prefix represents parameter name to provide value for.

Comment: That makes sense and is what I suspected when I first implemented the interface; however, I never actually see `ContainsPrefix` get called by the framework. I've updated my question with a bit more sample code to illustrate.

Comment: @CoreySmirt you are right. _Some_ (but not all) default model binders used by web api do not call ContainsPrefix before calling GetValue (I found that by inspecting their source code). I think that's an oversight of creators of those binders, not an expected behavior. Despite that, what I said above is still valid and I would better implement ContainsPrefix as it was supposed to be used.

Comment: The fact that not *all* model binders used by the Web API framework call `ContainsPrefix` is the key here. For simple types like `string`, `ContainsPrefix` will never be called.

Comment: But why is it called "prefix"? That seems to imply it represents the parent(s) of a nested property.

Comment: @xr280xr I have no idea honestly.

Comment: I’m going to *guess* that “prefix” is meant in terms of `a=` is a prefix in the query string `a=2&b=43`. When I read the method name, I thought “so if key `abc` exists then it must return `true` if I pass `a` and then I can do an acceptably efficient enumeration all the keys in the `IValueProvider` by going through the alphabet” but that is **not** the case. It would be better named `ContainsKey()`.

Comment: I imagine the reason it's called `ContainsPrefix` and not `ContainsKey` is because it's checking for prefixes :-)  If you have a query parameter like "class.property", you can call `ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix("class.")` to see if you should try for any such keys.  Naturally, `"class.property"` is a prefix of the empty string, so you can still use it like an imagined `ContainsKey` if you like.

Answer (score 3):

Here is parts of [Pride Parrot How to create a custom session value provider](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/7/how_to_create_a_custom_session_value_provider) article

> The `ContainsPrefix` method is called by the model binder to determine
>   whether the value provider can resolve the data for a given prefix.

If you have `SessionValueProvider`

```
public class SessionValueProvider: IValueProvider
{
    public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[prefix] != null;
    }

    public ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Session[key] == null)
            return null;

        return new ValueProviderResult(HttpContext.Current.Session[key],
            HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}


public class UserModel
{
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
    ...
}

public ViewResult SomeAction(UserModel userModel, ...)
{
    ...
}
```

> At the time of model binding the DefaultModelBinder checks with the
>   value providers could they return value for the parameter AccountNo by
>   calling the ContainsPrefix method. If none of the value providers
>   registered eariler could return the value our SessionValueProvider
>   checks with session whether such a parameter is stored and if yes it
>   return the value.